# List regrouping based on values in Python

Tags: python, list

I have been trying to convert some data, first value in each group is the group identifier:

```
data = [(a, 1, 2), (a, 3, 4), (b, 5, 6)]
```

into

```
data = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6)]]
```

What is the simplest way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `data` list is sorted by the grouping key, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: from operator import itemgetter

In [3]: data = [(a, 1, 2), (a, 3, 4), (b, 5, 6)]

In [4]: [[l[1:] for l in group] for _, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))]
Out[4]: [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6)]]
```